# Mysql: count child tables for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have four tables that contain some fields

```
1. user(id, name, email, password, .....)
2. policy1(id, userid, ....)
3. policy2(id, userid, ....)
4. policy3(id, userid, ....)
```

Now this is clear that user's *primary key* `(id)` is *foreign key* in other three tables.

I want to fetch total number of tables against each user that contain user `id` in that table.

for example:

```
user id 1 has entry in any two tables, 
user id 2 has entry in three tables, 
user id 3 has entry in any single table
```

Result should be like

```
id    total
1     2
2     3
3     1
```

I tried using `Left Join` but that I could not get the expected result.

Comment: `Total number of tables`? Such that the `number of tables where an id could be in`?

Comment: Yes, i want to fetch in which policy table user id exist and simply want to count them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the count for each user and then add the values together to get the final result.  I am using a `LEFT JOIN` to return all `user` rows even if there is not a matching value in the other tables.  If you only want the users with values in the other tables, then you can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select u.id,
  Coalesce(CntP1, 0) + Coalesce(CntP2, 0) + Coalesce(CntP3, 0) TotalCount
from `user` u
left join
(
  select count(*) CntP1, userid
  from policy1
  group by userid
) p1
  on u.id = p1.userid
left join
(
  select count(*) CntP2, userid
  from policy2
  group by userid
) p2
  on u.id = p2.userid
left join
(
  select count(*) CntP3, userid
  from policy3
  group by userid
) p3
  on u.id = p3.userid
```